# How to test behavior of parametrized constructor with JMockit? (New with JMockit)

Tags: java, jmockit

I have a factory class which constructor takes two parameter. Depending on that parameters the factory creates four different types of classes or throws IllegalArgumentExceptions in case of invalid arguments.

First I need to test if the appropirate class is created depending on the given parameters.
Second I need to verify the correct Exception in case of invalid parameters.

For testing the correct class is build in the factory I can fake the expected class and verify their instantiation.
But I don't know how to deal with @Tested to set up specific parameters in the constructor.

I coudn't find any usable hint neither in the JMockit documentation nor by searching the internet.

Below is a sample factory class and a sample of a class created by the factory (the others are similar).

```
public class WorkerFactory {
    
    private Worker worker;
    
    public WorkerFactory(final String type, final String subtype) {
        
        if(type == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("type");
        if(subtype == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("subtype");
        
        if(type.equals("One")) {
            if(subtype.equals("A")) worker = new One_A();
            else if(subtype.equals("B")) worker = new One_B();
            else throw new IllegalArgumentException("subtype");
        }
        else if(type.equals("Two")) {
            if(subtype.equals("A")) worker = new Two_A();
            else if(subtype.equals("B")) worker = new Two_B();
            else throw new IllegalArgumentException("subtype");
        }
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("type");
    }

    public Worker getWorker() { return worker; }
    
}



public interface Worker {
    
    public void doWork();

}



public class One_A implements Worker {

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName());
    }

}
```

And a very stupid skeleton for the requiered test BUT without using JMockit.

```
package application;

import org.junit.Test;

public class WorkerFactoryTest {

    WorkerFactory cut;

    @Test
    public final void testWorkerFactory() {
        
        cut = new WorkerFactory("One", "A");
        cut.getWorker().doWork();
        
        cut = new WorkerFactory("One", "B");
        cut.getWorker().doWork();

        cut = new WorkerFactory("Two", "A");
        cut.getWorker().doWork();
        
        cut = new WorkerFactory("Two", "A");
        cut.getWorker().doWork();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testWorkerFactoryExceptions() {
        
        try {
            cut = new WorkerFactory("Three", "C");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            cut = new WorkerFactory("One", "C");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                
    }

}

``

EDIT (2020.07.02):
The assertThrows(..) from JUnit is one way to verify exceptions. But I use still the old style try/catch variant encapsulated in functions like verifyNoException(errorMessage) with a fail(...) if i caught one or verifyXyzException(expectedExceptionMessage) with a fail(...) if I cought none. This gives me a better control over the exceptions I catch by even a good readability. A time ago i read about some drawbacks about assertThrows over the old fashin style but I can't remeber what they are.

Putting constructor logic in an init(..) method as suggested by JMockit is what I do indeed (the given example did not for simplification). But I still want to test the constructor and not the private initializer method(s). Also I prefere a design where a object gets fully initialized by constructor parameters because I don't like the (boring and ugly) setter calls. 
And verifying the parameters passed in is even a good one in my opinion.
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Tested annotation is useful in 90% of scenarios - empty constructor or constructors where all the args can be passed mocks via @Injectable.  That's not the scenario you are in due to you trying to test the permutations through your constructor.

As an aside, JMockit is poking you and saying you might want to reconsider your design.  For example, shift that constructor logic to an "init(..)" method (call it whatever) and you'd find things easier to work with, and likely a better overall design.  Likewise, constructors-throwing-exceptions is poor design, which the init(..) would get you away from.  But I digress...

Your testWorkerFactory(..) is fine as-is.  There's no easy way to do permutations of constructor arguments, so what you've got is fine.  Brute force is fine.  Everything doesn't have to be JMockit, JUnit is still OK.

For testWorkerFactoryExceptions, I'd make use of assertThrows(..) as it is much cleaner and guarantees that you receive the expected throw.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jeff. I think I have to study the @Injection annotation again and fiddle a bit around with it. 
It's true that not every thing has to be done with JMockit but I think it's a good style to use a standardized testdesign trough the entire project...